# MAMP Databases not showing up after update and transfer

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

Okay so I updated MAMP earlier because I was having permissions issues after updating OSX. I tried chown etc to no avail.
I made a copy of my db and htdocs folders and added them back into the MAMP folder post install. Now in the MAMP PHPMyAdmin, I can't see the databases at all.

Before the update, I could see them but got warnings/errors when attempting to access them.

Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: You should have done a proper backup and restore, not just copy the files.

Comment: The official MAMP site says to just copy and paste, any way I can recover this now? I still have all the original MAMP files.

Comment: Downgrade to the previous version, copy the original files back to their original location. Then do a MySQL dump of the data before you do anything else. Update. Restore the data from the dump.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment, but my reps are too low ; )

1. Restart your WIN/MAC after update.

if step 1. not working, then you copy/pasted files to different folders then required. Please check out that!

PS: copy/paste (backup) is fine.